# Bayesian updating - likelihood

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, bayesian, bayesian-network

I have a question about Bayesian updating.

I have a problem where I have an event $A$ with three possible outcomes: $(A(1),A(2),A(3))$. I need to estimate the probability of each outcome.

I am able to define the prior probability of each outcome by using literature, let's say $$P(A(1))=0.8,P(A(2))=0.1,P(A(3))=0.1$$

Then, I can find a pdf for each outcomes by performing some experiments. Each outcome $(A(1), A(2), A(3))$ follows a Gaussian distribution with mean $(m_1, m_2,m_3)$ and standard deviation $(s_1, s_2,s_3)$.

Now, can I update the probability of each outcome by knowing their prior probability and their pdf?

Can I use the pdf as a likelihood and omit the normalizing constant of the traditional Bayes formula?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you specified a prior on the probability of outcomes, you specified them as a constant.

I think what you're saying is you have a mixture distribution with 3 components. You sample $A \sim [.8,.1,.1]$ and the distribution on the data would be, conditional on the sampled $A$:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
X | m,s,A & \sim \sum_{i=1}^3\textrm{I}_{(A=A_i)}\textrm{N}(m_i,s_i)\\
A | \pi & \sim \textrm{Multinoulli}(\pi)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Where $\pi$ is the vector of probabilities. Note that if you integrate out $A$, you get:

\begin{equation}
X | m,s,\pi \sim \sum_{i=1}^3\pi_i\textrm{N}(m_i,s_i)\\
\end{equation}

Which is just a fully specified mixture distribution. In this setting $\pi$ is a parameter, not something included in the posterior. The only thing included in the posterior in this situation would be $A$.

What you could do instead is to place a hyper-prior on $\pi\sim\textrm{Dirichlet}(\alpha)$. This gives us the model:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
X | m,s,A & \sim \sum_{i=1}^3\textrm{I}_{(A=A_i)}\textrm{N}(m_i,s_i)\\
A | \pi & \sim \textrm{Multinoulli}(\pi)\\
\pi | \alpha &\sim \textrm{Dirichlet}(\alpha)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Which makes $\alpha$ the parameter at the deepest level of the hierarchy, and $\pi$ a part of the posterior distribution. Implementation of this requires Gibbs sampling, by sampling $A$ at each iteration and updating $\pi$ using the conjugacy of the Dirichlet to the Multinoulli/Multinomial.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It is very interesting and stimulating, and I really would like to code it in Matlab. However, my Bayesian and statistical background is not that strong. 

I do not get the reason why A|π needs to follow a multinoulli if I know from experiments that A follows a Gaussian mixture model (a gaussian distribution for each Ai). Can you kindly explain me this step? 

Regarding the Gibbs sampling, I should start sampling A from the Gaussian, and then move to assess π by using the sampled A as input to the Dirichlet, is that correct? 
Thank you!!